# Need help implementing two android activities?

Tags: java, android

I am trying two initiate two different activities using two buttons and the on click listener I am receiving the following error *Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete 
     ClassBody
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
     FieldDeclaration*

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.safaricom);



    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
    button2.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
}

private OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

          switch(v.getId()){

          case R.id.button1: 
               Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
               this.startActivity(intent);
               break;

          case R.id.button2:
              Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignUp.class);
           this.startActivity(intent);
           break;

          }

     }     
}
```

Comment: what line is this error occurring on?

Comment: On the very last line where there is a }

Answer (score 6):

A `;` is missing at the end.

```
private OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    ...

};
```

Answer (score 0):

you should probably change the onClick method to avoid a **duplicated local variable**

```
private OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = null;
          switch(v.getId()){
          case R.id.button1: 
               intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
               break;
          case R.id.button2:
               intent = new Intent(this, SignUp.class);
               break;
          }
          if (intent != null)
              this.startActivity(intent);
     }     
};
```

if you declare a variable **INSIDE** a switch it doesn't matter in which **case** you declare it, it is always inside the **switch**. This is why you have to use **break;** when you do not want to perform the other lines of code. 
You are inside the switch or not.